Android: Where does CameraInfo gets the information from?
I am working on an Android device with a camera set up in vertical orientation. The problem I am trying to fix is that, when you take a picture with the Camera app, the image gets saved in horizontal mode instead of vertical mode. Basically, it's like it's rotating the image when saving it.
I have managed to make the camera save the images in vertical orientation by modifying the LegacyCamera app's code in packages/apps/LegacyCamera/src/com/android/camera/Camera.java. I have done this in the storeImage function:
private void storeImage(final byte[] data, Location loc, int width,
                int height, long dateTaken, int previewWidth) {
            String title = Util.createJpegName(dateTaken);
            int orientation = Exif.getOrientation(data);
            CameraInfo info = CameraHolder.instance().getCameraInfo()[mCameraId];    // This is my change

            // Fix the orientation
            orientation = info.orientation;    // This is also my change

            Uri uri = Storage.addImage(mContentResolver, title, dateTaken,
                    loc, orientation, data, width, height);

This does work, however, I would prefer to not have to modify the system code. Instead, I would like to change some configuration file or something like that to make the orientation of the pictures correct.
So, basically, my question is, where does CameraInfo gets its information from? I have been trying to find something in the Android documentation or in the code, but I haven't been able to see where it's reading that value from. Is there a way I can find that?

What does "a camera set up in vertical orientation" mean? I am used to orientation being in reference to the device, not specifically just the camera. If you examine Configuration, what orientation is the device reporting?

Hi @CommonsWare, the device (and Configuration reports the same) is in portrait. The device is always in the same orientation and cannot rotate but the images are still being saved as landscape pictures instead of portrait.

Try this in your onActivityResult, this method will check if the phone was rotated while taking the picture and will change the orientation of the bitmap accordingly.
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == YOUR_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        
        Uri imageUri = data.getData();
        if (imageUri != null) {
            try (InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri)) {
                ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(inputStream);
                int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);
                imageBitmap = rotateBitmap(imageBitmap, orientation);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        
        yourImageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
    }


private Bitmap rotateBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int orientation) {
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    switch (orientation) {
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
            matrix.postRotate(90);
            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
            matrix.postRotate(180);
            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
            matrix.postRotate(270);
            break;
        default:
            return bitmap;
    }
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
}

